# Not able to inject filters in Controller for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, dependency-injection

Hi I have just started on Angular. I am using AngularJS 1.2.4.
Whenever I try to inject a filter in my controller I get the following error :

> Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider:
>   senderReceiverDetailInfoProvider <- senderReceiverDetailInfo <-
>   senderReceiverFilter

Here is my app.js :

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myapp", []);
```

Here is my myFilter.js:

```
    myApp.filter('senderReceiver',function(senderReceiverDetailInfo,index){
              conole.log("i",index);
           if(senderReceiverDetailInfo.description != ''){
                    return true;
           }else{
                    return false;
           }
    });
```

Here is my controller.js

```
      myApp.controller("myCtrl",'$scope','$http','PaymentService','senderReceiverFilter',
    function($scope,$http,PaymentService,senderReceiverFilter){
            $scope.sendReceiveFilter = senderReceiverFilter;
  }]);
```

And Finally here is my index.html in which I am trying to use the filter:

```
  <div  ng-repeat="detailInfo in senderReceiverDetail | filter : sendReceiveFilter">
    <label>{{$index + 1}}.</label><label>Type : {{detailInfo.lineType}}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <label>Description : {{detailInfo.description}}</label> 
   </div>                
                            </div>
```

And finally here are my questions:
     1) Why injection is not working?
     2) Am i using injected filter correctly(Assuming it is injectede somehow correctly) in my index.html?
     3) Also Have I declared filters correctly OR I have to declare them in separate module?
        If I declare them in separate module then how to inject them?
      E.g. if I do following instead of what I am doing right now for filter declaration:

```
    angular.module('myfilters',[]).filter('senderReceiver',function(senderReceiverDetailInfo,index){
              conole.log("i",index);
           if(senderReceiverDetailInfo.description != ''){
                    return true;
           }else{
                    return false;
           }
    });
```

and then inject above module in my myapp as dependency as follows:

```
      angular.module('myapp',['myfilters']);
```

Then how to use/inject the filter defined on module 'myfilters' in controller that I have defined in 'myapp' module?

4) And finally what is the better aproach? declaring filters in entirely spearate module or define it on main module like controller and services?

I know I am not much aware of dependency injection apart from the basic syntax. But I guess thats what I need. Thanks.

Comment: You should attach it to your module, not inject it in a controller

Comment: @PatrickReck Can you elaborate on what do you mean by attach? does that mean I should use second method? If yes then can you give small code example on how to use it in ng-repeat on html?

Comment: What is senderReceiverDetailInfo?

Comment: @ShawnC. It is the filter argument name i have used in my function which will be an object containing description as its property. So senderReceiverDetail is an array of such objects. This worked fine when I had defined the filter function directly on scope in my controller

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. I have stolen the filter from the *[AngularJS filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)*.

```
var MyApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

MyApp.filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(input, uppercase) {

        input = input || '';
        var out = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            out = input.charAt(i) + out;
        }

        if (uppercase) {
            out = out.toUpperCase();
        }

        return out;
    };
});
```

Now you will be able to use the filter in your templates like this: `{{ myObject.value | reverse }}`

Comment: In the same link they describe one way of injecting filters in Controllers under heading "Using filters in controllers, services, and directives". so I am doing the same thing. So why my injection is not working and theirs is working? OR custom filters have to be dedined like this and theirs is working because filter is the predefined service in Angular?

Comment: You will still have to declare it as posted in the answer. You only inject it into your controller, if you want to use it in your *ViewModel* instead of the *View*

Comment: Ok. I at least resolved the error on filter definition as suggested by you. However I cannot use it directly in my html without injecting it in controller and assigning it to scope. Is this correct behaviour? I mean I must do that or it can be used directly without injecting and assigning it to scope?

Comment: Also the second index variable that should be passed to filter function is not passed when I am trying to use that filter in ng-repeat

Comment: If you only have one module and made the filter on that, you shouldn't need to inject it anywhere to use it

Comment: yes If you see my initial code i am using only one module. Not sure why it is not called..also do you have any idea about why  second arument index is not passed?

Answer (score 0):

The filter that you are using with ng-repeat is this filter https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ng/filter/filter

The filter function has to be defined on the scope, simply try:

```
$scope.sendReceiveFilter = function(senderReceiverDetailInfo,index){
              conole.log("i",index);
           if(senderReceiverDetailInfo.description != ''){
                    return true;
           }else{
                    return false;
           }
    }
```

Update: To create your own filter function to filter array, you need to define to do something like

```
myApp.filter('senderReceiver', function () {
    function (senderReceivers, index) {
        var filteredsenderReceivers = [];
        // Fill the above array with filtered values from senderReceivers array
        return filteredsenderReceivers
    }
});
```

`senderReceivers` is an array

Use the filter as
`<div  ng-repeat="detailInfo in senderReceiverDetail |sendReceive">`

Comment: I had done that when I started out on this and that worked fine. but now I don't want to define it in my controller for the sake of modularity.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you are not defining your filter correctly. The filter should return a function. So update your filter to:

```
myApp.filter('senderReceiver', function(){
    return function(senderReceiverDetailInfo,index){
        console.log("i",index);
        if(senderReceiverDetailInfo.description != ''){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    };    
});
```

The way you declared the filter made Angular believe you were looking for dependencies named `senderReceiverDetailInfo` and `info`. As those are not defined as Angular assets, Angular will throw an error complaining it can't find a provider for the named asset in your case `senderReceiverDetailInfoProvider`, which is exactly what the logs state.

In case you want to use the filter in a controller, you can inject the [$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) and then simply call:

```
$filter('senderReceiver')(senderReceiverDetailInfo,index);
```

To answer your last question, you should put all related assets (be it controller, service or filter) in the same module.

Comment: Correct. I resovled it  by defining it the way you stated. However if I use this directly in html(ng-repeat specifically) without injecting it controller and assigning it to scope it doesn't work. is this normal behaviour? Also the second index parameter that should be passed whenever filter is used in ng-repeat is not passed why? and how i can achieve that?